# How to connect R to MySQL? Failed to connect to database: Error: Plugin caching_sha2_password could not be loaded

Tags: mysql, r, rmysql, r-dbi

I recently installed MySQL on my computer and am trying to connect RStudio to MySQL. I followed instructions in a book as well as instructions [here](http://mdsr-book.github.io/excerpts/mdsr-dbadmin.pdf). However, whenever I use `dbConnect()` or `src_mysql` in `RStudio`, I get this error message:

```
Error in .local(drv, ...) : 
  Failed to connect to database: Error: Plugin caching_sha2_password could not be loaded: The specified module could not be found
```

For example, I might login to MySQL using the command prompt in Windows

`mysql -u username -p`

and create a database as follows

`CREATE DATABASE myDatabase;`

and then in RStudio:

```
library(RMySQL)
db <- dbConnect(MySQL(), dbname = "myDatabase", user = "username", 
           password = "password", host = "localhost")
```

and my response is always that error message listed above.

And if you need it:
`sessionInfo()`

```
R version 3.5.2 (2018-12-20)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows >= 8 x64 (build 9200)
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The R mysql library depends on libmysqlclient/libmariadbclient. The missing caching_sha2_password seems to be an indicator that an old mysqlclient version or a libmariadbclient isn't installed. Only very recently did [caching_sha2_password get added to mariadb (3.0.8)](https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/CONC-312)

An alternative, like [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52864853/how-to-get-mysql-8-to-run-with-laravel/52865317#comment95016357_52865317), is to change the user in mysql to use a different authentication mechanism:

You set the user back to mysql_native_password:

```
ALTER USER 'username'@'localhost'
IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'password'
```

To make this the default for all newly created users change the my.cnf/my.ini setting `default_authentication_plugin=mysql_native_password`

Comment: With [Ubuntu Bug 1913676](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/mariadb-10.3/+bug/1913676) fixed now the Linux side should be solved for all (except Ubuntu-18.04 which is too old). Windows R connecting to MySQL-8.0 is [still a problem](https://github.com/r-dbi/RMariaDB/issues/134#issuecomment-888730781).

Comment: Really, this Windows R connecting to MySQL-8.0 isn't just still a problem, it's a REAL problem.  Thank you for referencing those comments danblack.

Answer (score 3):

Step 1: OPEN THE mySql 8.0 command client

Step 2: To list all users in database, type the command,
`select host,user from mysql.user;`

Step 3: Now reset the current user password as,
`set password for 'root'@'localhost'='yourpassword';`

Step 3: Last Step

`ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'yourpassword';`
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.12 sec)