# Password error in MYSQL (both are latest version)?

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-connector-python

Although I have changed the password format to mysqlnativepassword , the problem still persists . Could anyone help me correct this ?
[Python Shell](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VodZH.png)   [MYSQL Users](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PS3ia.png)  [Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wdVyC.png)

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please include information as text. Including the plugin in the MySQL users table would be useful.

Answer (score 0):

A more recent version of python connector will connect using the existing `caching_sha2_password` format.

You have not used `ALTER USER` to change the plugin for the user (like [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52864853/how-to-get-mysql-8-to-run-with-laravel/52865317#52865317)).

`default_authentication_plugin=` only changes the default for newly created users.